# I have saved a csv file from my old phone. now i want to import those contacts into windows phone

Tags: contacts

I have created a csv file from my old phone. I want those contacts in my new Windows  Phone 8 (Lumia 620). When I have imported those contacts to my windows mail account, only names and email IDs got imported and same again when I have imported such data from mail to phone, only the names are showing but no numbers.

So how can I get all those contacts with the numbers to my Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest and best way to do this, is to sign up for a Microsoft Account (you probably already have one, since your phone requires it for app purchases, etc).

Sign into http://www.outlook.com/ using the Microsoft Account you used to sync your phone. Click the / arrow next to Outlook and select "People" --

[image: switching to the people web app]

Then select "Import from file"

[image: select import from file]

Then select your type of file (CSV, Outlook) and hit browse, then select "Import contacts"

[image: select type of csv and then hit import]

In addition to getting your contacts synced to your phone, they also show up on the web, and if you get a new phone, you simply need to sign in with your Microsoft Account again and they'll be there.

On the flip side, if you have a bunch of contacts in your "People" app, you can export them from the Manage menu which will give you a nice CSV you can backup and take elsewhere if necessary --

[image: export contacts to file]

Comment: there is one problem with your method, outlook.com doesn't support CVS files with multiple entries. it also doesn't let you select multiple files and upload them all at once. so migrating lots of contacts will not be that easy.

Comment: Do you have a single CSV per contact? Generally, when I output I get a CSV with all contacts. (I haven't tried with duplicates, so I don't know how it handles those).

Comment: excuse me, I mean VCF. which outlook can't handle correctly. and older phones usually export their contact list as multiple VCF files (at least nokia phones)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about a week ago. After lots of searching around the web, I figured the only way to add new contacts to your WP8 device is to set up an online account and import you contacts there. If you go with an Outlook account (like I did) you can import your contacts using **Windows Live Mail**.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Nokia Lumia 620. Have you tried using the "Transfer my data" app that comes pre installed? It requires your old phone to have Bluetooth, but it works with pretty much any one that does.

It imports all contacts into the main Microsoft account on the phone. A bonus feature (only available if your old phone was a Nokia running Symbian) is that it will import all *recieved* SMS messages as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a Hotmail/Live Account, or sign in if you already have one
2. Go to people in Hotmail / Live / Outlook (click on Outlook icon)
3. Export a sample contact file in csv (create a new sample contact and export)
4. Copy your contact name, email, etc... in this format
5. Go to people in Hotmail and import the newly created CSV file
6. Sync your contacts on you Windows Phone

Wait for few minutes, as your contacts  are synced to your Windows Phone.