# Windows Phone Transfer Online Contacts

Tags: contacts, microsoft-account, 7.x

I have a new Windows Phone using a new Microsoft Account:

- How do I transfer my contacts stored in the cloud to my new phone? (more specifically, these are phone number associated with a Facebook account)
- If I can't do this, can I at least *access* these phone numbers without using my old phone?

[This article](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/people/how-do-i-get-contacts-onto-my-phone) almost seems to suggest I *have* to sign-in with my old MS account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to export from your old Microsoft account and the import that data into the new account. To do this, start at the bottom of [my answer here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/1668/1155), and then go to the top and work your way down.

If they are associated only with Facebook, simply go to

```
Settings -> email and accounts -> Add -> Facebook
```

If you have two Facebook accounts, I'm not sure how to help you out, as I don't think you can export data from one Facebook account into another, but maybe I just don't know how.

Comment: Bloody marvellous - thanks! The download/export of the contacts from my old account and the import to my new account worked great.

Answer (score 0):

If all your contacts are stored in your MS account, just login (in the phone settings > account) with your Live Id (Microsoft account) and all your data will be synchronized (using the Exchange protocol) to your phone

Comment: I'm already logged-in with another account. I just want to access my old phone numbers.

Comment: Setup another email book in log in with your old account. I thnk you can tell it to just synch contacts